# Linq query syntax to method query syntax

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Can anyone help with how to transform this LINQ query syntax to method syntax. 
It is because i need to use the Take() method.

```
IQueryable<QueueItem> rs = from a in ldb.QueueItems
                           join b in ldb.Robots on a.RobotId equals b.Id
                           join c in ldb.RobotsXEnvironments on b.Id equals c.RobotId
                           join d in ldb.Environments on c.EnvironmentId equals d.Id
                           join e in ldb.Releases on d.Id equals e.EnvironmentId
                           where e.ProcessKey == dropdown || a.Reference == query || 
                                       a.SpecificData.Contains(query) &&
                                       a.StartProcessing >= fromDate && a.EndProcessing <= toDate
                           select a;
```

Comment: One other option is just use take with it like that. If you put brackets around it. So 
(from a..... select a).Take(20)

Comment: The query isn't actually run until your convert it to a list or similar so you can apply the `take` to `rs` as a separate line and then 'run it. Multiple joins with method syntax is not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
IQueryable<QueueItem> rs = (from a in ldb.QueueItems
                           join b in ldb.Robots on a.RobotId equals b.Id
                           join c in ldb.RobotsXEnvironments on b.Id equals c.RobotId
                           join d in ldb.Environments on c.EnvironmentId equals d.Id
                           join e in ldb.Releases on d.Id equals e.EnvironmentId
                           where e.ProcessKey == dropdown || a.Reference == query || 
                                       a.SpecificData.Contains(query) &&
                                       a.StartProcessing >= fromDate && a.EndProcessing <= toDate
                           select a).take(number);
```

Comment: Thanks guys i cant believe the solution was so simple 